# ansible pip: recursively install wheels in a virtualenv

Tags: python, ansible, python-wheel

To install all wheels from a folder `/tmp/prod_wheel/` I do this:

```
$ cat playbook_install.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Install all wheels
      pip:
        name: "{{ query('fileglob', '/tmp/prod_wheel/*.whl') }}"
        virtualenv: "~/venv"
        virtualenv_command: /usr/bin/python3 -m venv ~/venv
```

It's working well.

Now I have a situation where wheels are in folders I don't known the names, e.g. `/tmp/data/*/*.whl` the `fileglob` does not glob folders (only files).

I use find to catch wheels, but what is the more compact way to install them in my virtualenv ?

```
$ echo playbook_catch_wheels.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Find to catch recursively all wheels
      find:
        paths: /vagrant/vagrant/*/dist/
        patterns: '*.whl'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extract the list of paths from your `find` result with the [`map` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) and pass it to `pip`, as you previously did with your `fileglob` lookup.

Taking for granted your actual `find` task returns what you expect (I still added `recurse` since you mentioned it) the following two tasks should meet your requirement:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Find to catch recursively all wheels
      find:
        paths: /vagrant/vagrant/*/dist/
        patterns: '*.whl'
        recurse: true
      register: wheel_search

    - name: Install all found wheels
      pip:
        name: "{{ wheel_search.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
        virtualenv: "~/venv"
        virtualenv_command: /usr/bin/python3 -m venv ~/venv
```

Note that the `find` solution is much more portable than the `fileglob` lookup, as it will work on a remote host if needed. Lookups are always running locally whereas find runs on the target host.